# Stretch image in FrameLayout to match neighboring element's height?

Tags: android, layout, height, imageview, android-framelayout

An instance of ImageView in a RelativeLayout with height set to fill_parent will stretch as the RelativeLayout does. E.g. if an EditText in the same layout is 10 lines tall, the image will stretch to 10 lines tall.

How can this behavior be replicated in a FrameLayout? The image's height set to fill_parent seems to behave the same as wrap_content, regardless of the height of the other items in the FrameLayout.

I'd prefer to handle this purely in the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a (possibly hack) workaround- wrapping the FrameLayout in a LinearLayout let me set the FrameLayout to fill_parent and so its children could stretch accordingly. So:

```
<LinearLayout
orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:measureAllChildren="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout ... >
    ... other stuff ...
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the ImageView will stretch to the height of the EditText.

Answer (score 2):

`FrameLayout` has all it's children views overlaid on the same area. Depending on your settings, you can change how the views are displayed. According to Android's [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html),

> The size of the frame layout is the
>   size of its largest child (plus
>   padding), visible or not (if the
>   FrameLayout's parent permits).

Also, from [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#framelayout)

> FrameLayout is the simplest type of
>   layout object. It's basically a blank
>   space on your screen that you can
>   later fill with a single object — for
>   example, a picture that you'll swap in
>   and out. All child elements of the
>   FrameLayout are pinned to the top left
>   corner of the screen; you cannot
>   specify a different location for a
>   child view. Subsequent child views
>   will simply be drawn over previous
>   ones, partially or totally obscuring
>   them (unless the newer object is
>   transparent).

In your example, the image in a `FrameLayout` will not be stretched to the dimensions of it's largest sibling, irrespective of using `fill_parent` or `wrap_content`.

Comment: Hmm, the documentation must be outdated, because I can easily specify another location for a child with layout_gravity (in 2.1). But regardless, I'm finding that an imageview will not stretch to the size of its largest sibling. I suspect I'm trying to practice what Romain says is not implemented 'til HoneyComb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606613/combining-wrap-content-on-parent-and-fill-parent-on-child/4607808#4607808

Comment: Sorry Nathan, I meant it does not change... corrected it. I think you will have to do it in code itself.