# conflict between wrap_content on parent and match_parent on child

Tags: android, android-layout, position, android-xml

I'm trying to understand the UI behavior when parent **layout_width/layout_height** is set to *wrap_content* while in son **layout_width/layout_height**  is set to *match_parent*. I found a old question in stackoverflow [combining wrap_content on parent and fill_parent on child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606613/combining-wrap-content-on-parent-and-fill-parent-on-child)

But the post writer tried to achieve that all his sons (buttons in his case) will be at the same height, the response refereed to this purpose and not to how this conflict is set.
For example in the following code i have written:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I ran this code and *CardView* width take occupied all the screen (it seems that layout_width (*match_parent*) in *CardView* overcome on layout_width (*wrap_content*) in *RelativeLayout*. While *CardView* height occupied only both TextViews and not all the screen ( it seems that layout_width (*wrap_content*) in *RelativeLayout* overcome on layout_width (*match_parent*) in *CardView*

I can't find any "rule" how the conflict should be set.
I hope someone can help me understanding the logic or facts on how this conflict is set?